# Pdf hyperlinks are not working in reactjs application?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I am using [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) package to display pdf files in my react application. I am using webpack to import the module i.e.

```
import { Document } from 'react-pdf/build/entry.webpack';
import abc from '../abc.pdf';
import xyz from '../xyz.pdf';
```

Using switch case to show different pdf which is working fine.

```
      switch (activeTab) {
        case tabs.abc:
            data = abc;
            break;
        case tabs.xyz:
            data = xyz;
            break;
```

Every pdf has a hyperlink which is working fine when opened with Adobe reader but rather not working (non-clickable) in the application. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post some more code how you are using it and what is not working?

Comment: updated the question, please check

Comment: How are you referring the pdfs in your component? Also are you facing any issues?

Comment: I am using webpack to import the pdfs and then using it as equivalent to data according to different cases. I do not face any other issues except the hyperlinks are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known [issue](https://github.com/nnarhinen/react-pdf/issues/12) and the solution based on those comments is to instead use Mozilla's [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)